# Azure Devops deployment group auto-configure script fails on Azure VM unable to access: vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-compute-emulator

I need to push a DevOps website from azure to IIS on Amazon or Microsoft (or locally).

When I run the script in the Azure VM, I get the error the domain vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net isn't accessible. I assume this is for advanced internal azure networking reasons.

What is the most appropriate way to publish one DevOps site into one IIS Web(app) site while others are running and perhaps managed by others? [I'm currently using this approach.](https://www.anupams.net/deploy-to-on-premise-devops/)

Comment: It worked well when I run the script in the Azure VM. If my VM is not connected to the Internet, I will get the same error message. Can you share your configuration and networking settings of your Azure VM?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have permission to, but if you do, I'd recommend setting up a deployment group or agent (deployment group for classic pipelines, agent for YAML) on the Windows Server hosting the site.

Once you set up a deployment group/agent, you'll want to configure your release pipeline to be set to use the newly registered agent or deployment group within your pipeline.

If you're using a classic (UI) pipeline, you'll want to add a new **Deployment Group Job** by clicking the ellipsis to the right of your stage name:
[image: Deployment Group Selection]

After you've added the deployment group job, you'll want to select the deployment group you've just added:
[image]

With that configured, you'll be running your pipeline on the IIS server you're deploying to, and you'll just need to add the **IISWebAppDeployemntOnMachineGroup@0** task to your release pipeline and point to the site you're deploying to:

[image]